# Implementing search bar and animating table view in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, deprecated

From the start when i was programming, i used the UISearchDisplayController. However, now it is deprecated for iOS 8 and above. I tried searching the web for an alternative solution but all of it only shows solutions only for swift. How would i implement the search bar without it being deprecated for iOS 9?

Another question would be that i have seen people animating their tableview such that when they scroll down it appears animated using Swift. Is it possible to do so using objective C? If yes, how would i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `nsnotifications` with an animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^(void) {
        _galery.alpha= 0;
        _galery.alpha = 1;
    }];
```